# How to Update an object in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my Array

```
$scope.tooltipsArray = [
              {
                  date: 2018-10-10T07:03:43.835Z,
                  text: 'name1'
              },

              {
                  date: 2018-09-29T18:30:00.000Z,
                  text: 'name2'
              }     
          ];
```

How can I update date to locale date format like this.

```
 $scope.tooltipsArray = [
              {
                  date: Wed Oct 10 2018 14:05:27 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
                  text: 'name1'
              },

              {
                  date: Sun Sep 30 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
                  text: 'name2'
              }     
          ];
```

I have used map() to do that. But it does not work

```
var vector = $scope.tooltipsArray.map(function (el) { return new Date(el.date).toLocaleDateString(); });
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this from `map()` in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code -

```
    $scope.tooltipsArray = [
                  {
                      date: "2018-10-10T07:03:43.835Z",
                      text: 'name1'
                  },

                  {
                      date: "2018-09-29T18:30:00.000Z",
                      text: 'name2'
                  }     
              ];

    var vector = $scope.tooltipsArray.map(function(el) {return { 'date':new Date(el.date).toString(),'text':el.text}});
    console.log(vector);
```

The output will be like below -

```
[
{date: "Wed Oct 10 2018 12:33:43 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)", text: "name1"}
{date: "Sun Sep 30 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)", text: "name2"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is there a `.value` key after `tooltipsArray`?

You assigned the array to `tooltipsArray`, so unless there's a Proxy involved, expect to access the array through `$scope.tooltipsArray`.

To fix it, just remove `.value`.

```
var vector = $scope.tooltipsArray.map(function (el) { return new Date(el.date).toLocaleDateString(); });
```

Comment: sorry it was my mistake i have edit my code please refer that thankyou

Comment: @sd_dewasurendra you can check my answer , I have used the date values in string if you are looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

1- Remove `.value` why is there in the first place?

2- You need to change the date inside the object and then return `el` instead of `date` if you just want the date to be changed, likewise:

```
    var vector = $scope.tooltipsArray.map(function(el) {
     el.date = new Date(el.date).toLocaleDateString();
     return el;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What map function does is going through array element one by one and run the callback function, so what you have to do is update the whole object or update one entry

el.date = new Date(el.date).toLocaleDateString();